# Can this Fighter/Assassin build and setup allow 2 assassinate auto critical sneak attacks on round 1?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, assassin

Suppose I'm playing in combat as a 2nd level fighter/3rd level rogue assassin, and at least one more party member surprises the enemy. We have higher initiative.

Can the assassin use his action to score the autocritical + sneak attack, and then use the fighter's action surge feature to use a ready action to repeat attack against the same target, triggered on some action taken by his other party member?

Comment: Hi Piero. Your question is extremely rambly and difficult to parse. Since you're asking if you can do something specific with a specific build and have it work out a specific way, could I suggest you edit this to just describe (clearly): the relevant parts of the build, the actions you're trying to take, and how you think it will work out, and strip out the rest? E.g. I'm pretty sure I can just delete the whole first paragraph, and strip the second down to "I'm making a fighter 2 / rogue 3, who will have action surge, the assassin archetype, and the alert feat and stealth expertise."

Comment: you are right i tend to do that, i will edit

Comment: One thing that might help with these scenarios is the writing practice of [voyage out, voyage in](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/writing-voyage-out-voyage-back). You voyaged out already -- this would be the voyage in.

Comment: Thanks for taking that request on board.  That's quite a good editing effort! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, this is legal

As long as you hit with both attacks -- the one on your turn and the one on your ally's -- you can autocrit with Sneak Attack damage on both. All the requirements of Sneak Attack and Assassinate are fulfilled.

#### Other builds that can do this

These MC builds achieve the same thing at a later level, but here's to illustrate that you can do this without Action Surge, using just your regular Action.

- A Sorcerer 3/Rogue Assassin 3 with Quickened Spell

  - Quicken Green Flame Blade or Booming Blade (GFB/BB) for a bonus action, and then use their action to Ready another GFB/BB
- A Wizard 5/Rogue 3, or Sorc 5/Rogue 3, or Lore Bard 6/Rogue 3

  - Pre-cast *haste* to receive an extra action before the surprise round begins. During the surprise round, use that extra action to make a regular Attack, and use your regular action to Ready a second regular attack (you may not ready a spell as Readying a spell requires Concentration, which *haste* already takes up)
- A Frenzy Barb 3/Rogue 3, Strength-based

  - Use Frenzied Rage as a bonus before the ambush, and during the surprise round, use their bonus action to make one weapon attack. They can use their action to Ready another attack.